# MySQL Connection Pooling for Multiple Processes

Tags: c#, mysql, optimization, database-connection

I am creating a wiki engine to learn (more) about web programming. The basic design is to have php scripts that simply run a C# program to do the heavy lifting of database operations and generating html for the browser. However, I have run into a bottleneck, which is that every MySQL connection takes about 1.4 seconds, where the entire rest of the C# and PHP code takes about 0.4 seconds.

So, I really want/need to speed up the initial event of connecting to the database.

Is it possible to set up a connection pool in MySQL for multiple processes, so that several C# processes can connect to my database very quickly, instead of taking over a second? Or are connection pools only for a single process that uses multiple threads?

Or, is there any other way to speed up the database connection for multiple C# processes?